# is it possible to read the text written in a sticky note using a script in linux?

Tags: python, ruby, perl

I am using sticky notes in ubuntu . And was wondering if it would be possible to read the text written in sticky notes using any scripting language .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant the "Sticky Notes" applet you can add to your panel then yes you can read that notes too.

The XML file containing all notes typically is located at `~/.gnome2/stickynotes_applet`.

You just have to parse the information you need out of it. The structure should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stickynotes version="2.30.0">
    <note title="10/31/2010" x="658" y="176" w="477" h="418">Some text</note>
</stickynotes>
```

Where `x`stands for the notes position on the x-axis, `y`for its position on the y-axis, `w` stands for the width and `h` stands for the height.

It should be pretty simple to build a parser for it using Perl for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can do it using the sticky notes, but assuming if you use Tomboy, you can do it.

You need `tomboycli`, a Python script which provides access to Tomboy through d-bus.

The project is hosted on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/tomboycli/). Maybe you can study this to make your own implementation if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The tomboy notes are saved as xml files so you could write a xml parser.